# Layering JPanels with the bottom layer a background image

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, jlayeredpane

I am trying to program a board game. I want to load an image of the game board and then load a transparent grid over it. I wrote a custom panel to draw the image and added it to a layered panel as level 0. Then I make a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout` and added it at level 1. The layered pane is then put into a scroll pane to account for the background image being kinda large. The hope is to have most of the grid be transparent at any given time but if a player piece enters a square then I will set that square to be a color representing the piece. However when I set the top panel to transparent (by making a call to `setOpaque(false)`) I just get a white background, no image is present. Why is this?

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel
{
   private Image image;

   public ImagePanel(Image image) 
   {
      this.image = image;
      this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(936,889));
    }

   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
   {
      g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
   }
}
```

Here is the code in the main program which creates the panels and nests them. backBoard is the outer frame. It is setVisible later on so that's not an issue.

```
BufferedImage boardImage = null;
       try
       {
           boardImage = ImageIO.read(new File("Clue Board.jpg"));
       }
       catch(IOException e)
       {

       }

   ImagePanel background = new ImagePanel(boardImage); //load clue board image

   JPanel gameBoard = new JPanel (new GridLayout(24,24)); //yet to add actual squares
   gameBoard.setSize(936,889);
   gameBoard.setOpaque(false);

   JLayeredPane lPane = new JLayeredPane();
   lPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(936,889));
   lPane.add(background, new Integer(0));
   lPane.add(gameBoard, new Integer(1));

   JScrollPane layerScroller = new    JScrollPane(lPane,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
   backBoard.add(layerScroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Why not set the layout manager of the board to BorderLayout and add the grid panel to it?

Answer (score 2):

- Try calling `super.paintComponent(..)` like so:

  ```
  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
  {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
  }
  ```
- Dont call `JFrame#setSize(..)` use an [appropriate `LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and override `getPrefferedSize(..)` of `JPanel` which will return the correct size and then call `pack()` on `JFrame` instance before setting it visible.

Here is an example of how your `ImagePanel` class should look:

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel
{
    private int width,height;
    private Image image;

    public ImagePanel(Image image) 
    {
          this.image = image;

          //so we can set the JPanel preferred size to the image width and height
          ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.image);
          width = ii.getIconWidth();
          height = ii.getIconHeight();
     }

     //so our panel is the same size as image
     @Override
     public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
          return new Dimension(width, height);
     }

     @Override
     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
     {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about setting preferred size. However it still just paints a white screen instead of the image

Comment: One of my friends says he has got it working. I don't have access to the code at the moment. Thanks everyone!